# Render points of Both a filled and unfilled Ellipse to Array in C#

Tags: c#, math, drawing, ellipse

Does anyone know of any code to render an Ellipse to an array in C#? I had a look about, I couldn't find anything that answered my problem.

Given the following array:

```
bool[,] pixels = new bool[100, 100];
```

I'm looking for functions to render both a hollow and filled ellipse within a rectangular area. e.g:

```
public void Ellipse(bool[,] pixels, Rectangle area)
{
    // fill pixels[x,y] = true here for the ellipse within area.
}

public void FillEllipse(bool[,] pixels, Rectangle area)
{
    // fill pixels[x,y] = true here for the ellipse within area.
}

Ellipse(pixels, new Rectangle(20, 20, 60, 60));
FillEllipse(pixels, new Rectangle(40, 40, 20, 20));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the start you say `Does anyone know of any code to render an Ellipse to an array` then after you say `Given the following array...
I'm looking for functions to render both a hollow and filled ellipse`. Do you want to turn an ellipse into a `bool[,]` or a `bool[,]` to a hollow or filled ellipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
public class EllipseDrawer
{
    private static PointF GetEllipsePointFromX(float x, float a, float b)
    {
        //(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1
        //(y/b)^2 = 1 - (x/a)^2
        //y/b = -sqrt(1 - (x/a)^2)  --Neg root for upper portion of the plane
        //y = b*-sqrt(1 - (x/a)^2)
        return new PointF(x, b * -(float)Math.Sqrt(1 - (x * x / a / a)));
    }

    public static void Ellipse(bool[,] pixels, Rectangle area)
    {
        DrawEllipse(pixels, area, false);
    }

    public static void FillEllipse(bool[,] pixels, Rectangle area)
    {
        DrawEllipse(pixels, area, true);
    }

    private static void DrawEllipse(bool[,] pixels, Rectangle area, bool fill)
    {
        // Get the size of the matrix
        var matrixWidth = pixels.GetLength(0);
        var matrixHeight = pixels.GetLength(1);

        var offsetY = area.Top;
        var offsetX = area.Left;

        // Figure out how big the ellipse is
        var ellipseWidth = (float)area.Width;
        var ellipseHeight = (float)area.Height;

        // Figure out the radiuses of the ellipses
        var radiusX = ellipseWidth / 2;
        var radiusY = ellipseHeight / 2;

        //Keep track of the previous y position
        var prevY = 0;
        var firstRun = true;

        // Loop through the points in the matrix
        for (var x = 0; x <= radiusX; ++x)
        {
            var xPos = x + offsetX;
            var rxPos = (int)ellipseWidth - x - 1 + offsetX;

            if (xPos < 0 || rxPos < xPos || xPos >= matrixWidth)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var pointOnEllipseBoundCorrespondingToXMatrixPosition = GetEllipsePointFromX(x - radiusX, radiusX, radiusY);
            var y = (int) Math.Floor(pointOnEllipseBoundCorrespondingToXMatrixPosition.Y + (int)radiusY);
            var yPos = y + offsetY;

            var ryPos = (int)ellipseHeight - y - 1 + offsetY;

            if (yPos >= 0)
            {
                if (xPos > -1 && xPos < matrixWidth && yPos > -1 && yPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, yPos] = true;
                }

                if(xPos > -1 && xPos < matrixWidth && ryPos > -1 && ryPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, ryPos] = true;
                }

                if (rxPos > -1 && rxPos < matrixWidth)
                {
                    if (yPos > -1 && yPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, yPos] = true;
                    }

                    if (ryPos > -1 && ryPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, ryPos] = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            //While there's a >1 jump in y, fill in the gap (assumes that this is not the first time we've tracked y, x != 0)
            for (var j = prevY - 1; !firstRun && j > y - 1 && y > 0; --j)
            {
                var jPos = j + offsetY;
                var rjPos = (int)ellipseHeight - j - 1 + offsetY;

                if(jPos == rjPos - 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if(jPos > -1 && jPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, jPos] = true;
                }

                if(rjPos > -1 && rjPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, rjPos] = true;
                }

                if (rxPos > -1 && rxPos < matrixWidth)
                {
                    if(jPos > -1 && jPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, jPos] = true;
                    }

                    if(rjPos > -1 && rjPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, rjPos] = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            firstRun = false;
            prevY = y;
            var countTarget = radiusY - y;

            for (var count = 0; fill && count < countTarget; ++count)
            {
                ++yPos;
                --ryPos;

                // Set all four points in the matrix we just learned about
                //  also, make the indication that for the rest of this row, we need to fill the body of the ellipse
                if(yPos > -1 && yPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, yPos] = true;
                }

                if(ryPos > -1 && ryPos < matrixHeight)
                {
                    pixels[xPos, ryPos] = true;
                }

                if (rxPos > -1 && rxPos < matrixWidth)
                {
                    if(yPos > -1 && yPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, yPos] = true;
                    }

                    if(ryPos > -1 && ryPos < matrixHeight)
                    {
                        pixels[rxPos, ryPos] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Although, oddly, the X position of the rectangle does not seem to be honoured.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you wanted just an ellipse of the size of the rectangle or positioned based on the X and Y offsets as well. I'll update my answer tonight with positioning.

Comment: X an Y actually, the code doesn't appear to use either area.X or area.Y??? Otherwise, I'm happy to provide the bounty for this answer it's pretty much there. Any chance you can update it to include the positioning of the rectangle?

Comment: The answer has been updated, glad to hear it's been helpful so far

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks for the info. Is there any way to make the unfilled version render only the thinnest possible outline? Like the green section I've modified in this picture? http://i50.tinypic.com/evc9k9.png
Again, thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Updated to make the border thinner

Comment: Absolutely outstanding :) - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Although there already seems to be a [perfectly valid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11241715/650012) with source code and all to this question, I just want to point out that the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project also contains a lot of efficient [source code](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest) for drawing and filling different polygon types (such as ellipses) in so-called `WriteableBitmap` objects.

This code can easily be adapted to the general scenario where a 2D-array (or 1D representation of a 2D-array) should be rendered in different ways.

For the ellipse case, pay special attention to the `DrawEllipse...` methods in the *WriteableBitmapShapeExtensions.cs* file and `FillEllipse...` methods in the *WriteableBitmapFillExtensions.cs* file, everything located in the *trunk/Source/WriteableBitmapEx* sub-folder.

Answer (score 1):

This more applies to all languages in general, and I'm not sure why you're looking for things like this in particular rather than using a pre-existing graphics library (homework?), but for drawing an ellipse, I would suggest using the midpoint line drawing algorithm which can be adapted to an ellipse (also to a circle):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

I'm not sure I fully agree that it's a generalisation of Bresenham's algorithm (certainly we were taught that Bresenham's and the Midpoint algorithm are different but proved to produce identical results), but that page should give you a start on it. See the link to the paper near the bottom for an algorithm specific to ellipses.

As for filling the ellipse, I'd say your best bet is to take a scanline approach - look at each row in turn, work out which pixels the lines on the left and right are at, and then fill every pixel inbetween.

Comment: This is not homework, I'm just not that great at Maths, which is why this was so specific.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would do is iterate over each element of your matrix, and check whether some ellipse equation evaluates to true

[image]

taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse

What I would start with is something resembling

```
        bool[,] pixels = new bool[100, 100];

        double a = 30;
        double b = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++ )
            {
                double x = i-50;
                double y = j-50;
                pixels[i, j] = (x / a) * (x / a) + (y / b) * (y / b) > 1;
            }
```

and if your elipse is in reverse, than just change the `>` to `<`

For a hollow one, you can check whether the difference between `(x / a) * (x / a) + (y / b) * (y / b)` and `1` is within a certain threshold.  If you just change the inequality to an equation, it will probably miss some pixels.

Now, I haven't actually tested this fully, so I don't know if the equation being applied correctly, but I just want to illustrate the concept.